# Only change a property of an instance of a material?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my code I am creating a clone of an RawImage in my scene. The issue is I want to merely change a property of the material attached to the clone, but whenever I do this, it automatically changes the property for the standard material. Thus, the property of the material for the original RawImage gets changed.
I thought about those workarounds already:

1. create multiple prefabs beforehand.
2. Create a new Material

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your raw images are referencing the same material. You need to create a new instance of it. I'm gonna assume that you tried to do it by hand. What I suggest is to do it programmatically - after instantiating a new instance of `RawImage` you also create a new instance of `Material` for your new image which is a copy of the original.

### Here's an extension method for doing that:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public static class RawImageExtensions
{
    public static RawImage CloneWithMaterial(this RawImage target)
    {
        RawImage newInstance = Object.Instantiate(target, target.transform.parent);
        newInstance.material = new Material(newInstance.material);

        return newInstance;
    }
}
```

### Usage example:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class RawImageTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private RawImage target = null;

    private void Start()
    {
        RawImage image = target.CloneWithMaterial();
        image.material.color = Color.black;

        image.transform.position = new Vector2(
            image.transform.position.x,
            image.transform.position.y - 50f);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I thought of the same solution on unity. I hoped that there would be another way of doing this, but I you, too, wrote this solution, I assume it's the right and best way to handle it.